# How to code markup for Product in ItemList?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have adapted a code taken from example 2 on http://schema.org/ItemList

How do I use it together with `Product`? On frontpage and some other pages I have a list of products for which I would like to have a better markup.

The following code gives the error

> A value for the position field is required.

but `Product` doesn't have a position, so if there is a value for `position` it gives different error.

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <meta itemprop="numberOfItems" content="10" />

        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

            <!-- <meta itemprop="position" content="1" /> -->

            <a href="#" itemprop="url">
                <img src="asdf.jpg" itemprop="image">
                <div class="product-list__title" itemprop="name">
                    Product name
                </div>
                <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <div itemprop="price">
                        $12
                    </div>
                    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
                </div>
            </a>

        </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`itemListElement`](https://schema.org/itemListElement) property has three expected values:

- `ListItem`
- `Text`
- `Thing`

[`ListItem`](https://schema.org/ListItem) is also a `Thing`, but it’s listed explicitly because it has a special role here: `ListItem` provides the [`position`](https://schema.org/position) property. If you need to convey the position of the list items, you have to provide `ListItem` values.

Note that not every `ItemList` needs this. Your example with using `Product` values is fine (apart from the `meta` element which can’t be a child of `ul`), and unless you try to qualify for Google’s rich result (this is what the error message is about), you could keep it like that.

If you do want to provide the positions, an `itemListElement` could look like this:

```html
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
  <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  <div itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <!-- your Product -->
  </div>
</li>
```